# Finding and loading the files (R.h) for R [I have a MAC]

Tags: r, c, macos, terminal

I have writing a simple HelloWorld! program in C to incorporate in an R function hello().

# //* C-File (named as hello.c) *//

```
#include<R.h>
void hello1(){
    Rprintf("Hello, world!\n");
  }
}
```

# R file hello.R

```
hello = function(){
  .Call("hello.c")
}
```

** The two files are stored in the working directory of R.

Steps I followed;

1. Ran the R file. The function hello is created.
2. Tried to see the output using hello()

But it did not work. It says hello.c is not found in load table.

## I researched some more and found that I need to compile the C file first.

When I run it in the Mac terminal using clang hello.c / gcc hello.c, I found out that the R.h file is not found.

I tried forcing the path as #include<path/R.h>

And it says that another libextern.h file is not found.

## I have been trying all day to no avail.

My problem may be solved if somehow the compiler knows where all the ".h" files are located. But I don't know much about it. I would love to hear your ideas/suggestions on this.

Comment: If you do `R CMD compile hello.c` then R itself will know where its headers are.  Ditto `R CMD SHLIB hello.o` etc.  Take advantage of that!   Else the `inline` package can help too.

Comment: R CMD SHLIB did not work in the terminal. But I got it done using system2("R",c("CMD","SHLIB","hello.c")) in R itself. Thank You.